# Разработка 3D-игр под Android

Tags: android, разработка-игр, 3d

Какие существуют инструменты разработки игр под `Android` помимо `Unity`?

Comment: Форум не предназначен для опросов. Если у вас какая-то конкретная проблема - задавайте вопрос. Список инструментов для разработки 3д игр вы можете найти в гугле.

Comment: Согласен, в первую очередь хотелось бы узнать мнение людей которые работают именно каким то из перечисленных в ответах инструментами и услышать + и -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Небольшой список:

- [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/ru/)
- [ShiVa3D](http://www.shiva-engine.com/)
- [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
- [CryEngine](https://www.cryengine.com/)
- [Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/) - бесплатный\платный 79$
- [Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) бесплатный, если суммарный доход за квартал не превышает   - 3000$. Если доход превышает 3000$, то Вы платите разработчикам 5% от суммарного    дохода от продукта за квартал.
- [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) - бесплатный
- [Game Maker Studio](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker) - платный 99$
- [Monkey](http://www.monkey-x.com/) -платный 99$
- [GDevApp](https://gdevapp.com/)
- [Angel 2D](http://angel2d.com/)
- [App Game Kit](https://www.appgamekit.com/)
- [Defold](http://www.defold.com/) - бесплатный
- [Buildbox](https://www.buildbox.com/) - бесплатный\платный 2675$
- Gamekit - бесплатный
- [INSTEAD](http://instead.syscall.ru/ru/index.html) - бесплатный
- [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/corona-sdk/) -бесплатный/платный 550$
- [LIBgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) - бесплатный
- [ORX](http://orx-project.org/) - бесплатный
- [jPCT](http://www.jpct.net/) 3D engine - бесплатный
- [Tululoo Game Maker](http://www.tululoo.com/) - бесплатный
- [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/) - бесплатный, но поддержка Android только в платной версии
- [Gideros Studio](http://giderosmobile.com/) - платный 149$
- [Marmalade](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/) - платный 150$ в год
- [Ardor3D](http://www.ardor3d.com/) - бесплатный
- [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) - бесплатный
- MOMINIS - бесплатный
- IRM - бесплатный
- [Linderdaum Engine SDK](http://www.linderdaum.com/home/index.php?title=Main_Page) - бесплатный
- [Moai SDK](http://getmoai.com/moai-sdk.html) - бесплатный\платный 99$
- [Esenthel Engine](http://www.esenthel.com/) - платный 150$
- [IwGame Engine](http://www.drmop.com/index.php/marmalade-sdk/iwgame-engine/) - бесплатный
- [DX Studio](http://www.dxstudio.com/features.aspx) - бесплатный
- [BatteryTech Engine](http://www.batterytechsdk.com/) - бесплатный\платный 249$
- [e3roid](http://www.e3roid.com/) - бесплатный
- [Antiryad Gx 3](http://www.arkham-development.com/) - бесплатный
- [gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/) - бесплатный
- [Ethanon Engine](http://ethanonengine.com/) - бесплатный
- [PGS4A](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example) - бесплатный
- [Crystal Space 3D](http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/Main_Page) - бесплатный
- Godot Game Engine - бесплатный
- Multimedia Fusion 2 -бесплатный 30 дней/платный
- Ignifuga -бесплатный

Comment: А как же cocos2d-x-наше-все?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian их есть у меня в списке. Вы проглядели)  Надо было наверное его повыше поместить

Comment: Тут много инструментов, а что выбрать? На каком из них будет проще работать?
Какой инструмент будет отвечать требованиям: прост в освоении, мощный, не требует вложений в начале разработки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не, не, то совсем другое, я про http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

Answer (score 3):

- [Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4)
- [Project Anarchy](http://www.havok.com) - Движок от Havok.
- [Marmalade](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com) - кроссплатформенный SDK.

Можно еще посмотреть [тут](http://gcup.ru/load/engines/3). Огромный список движков на любой вкус и цвет.