# что нужно знать чтобы создавать игры под android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом, искал в инете не смог найти, надеюсь здесь найду ;)

Comment: Все придельно просто - Учить `java`

Comment: Стефан, вот тут смотрите: http://bfy.tw/BfdR

Comment: скачать Unity? :)

Comment: Нужно лишь уметь программировать.

Comment: тут еще зависит что имеется в виду под словами `создавать игры`. Клиентская часть или серверная. Или и то и другое? ....... вот список двигов для андройда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548497/191482   .......... в целом нужно знать ЯП и уметь иногда в БД и сетевые протоколы

Comment: @SviatVolkov скачать юнити не достаточно :D

Comment: короче, я понял учить java core, одновременно изучать движок на котором будешь работать и некоторые знания из андроид!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ зависит от того, что вы вкладываете в понятие "создание игр". Если вопрос именно о создании игры целиком - то это включает в себя огромное множество умений (3д моделирование, создание музыки и видео/аудио монтаж, программирование, написание сюжета и т.д.). Если интересует именно это - почитайте про indie game dev. Зачастую именно solo indie разработчики обладают этими, и многими другими навыками, о которых, Вам будет полезно узнать.

Если же речь именно о программировании, то тут, опять же, всё зависит от выбранной области. Программисты в game dev'е так же, бывают разные - кто-то занимается программированием серверной части, кто-то игрового движка, кто-то игрового интерфейса. Список используемых технологий сильно зависит от того, что конкретно программируется.

Я бы дал такой совет:
- Если вы хотите научиться создавать полноценные игры самостоятельно, то порекомендовал бы посмотреть в сторону Unity (https://unity3d.com). Это готовый игровой движок и специальная среда разработки под него, которая позволяет и код писать, и визуальную часть с анимациями разрабатывать. 
- Если же вы хотите научиться game dev'у для того, чтобы потом работу найти, то, возможно, более правильным было бы не спрашивать аудиторию тут, а зайти на сайт с вакансиями (тот же hh.ru) и найти компании, занимающиеся разработкой игр в Вашем регионе. Посмотреть их список требований, и понять на обучение чему стоит потратить время именно оттуда.