# Как создать мобильные игры c Unity 3D?

Tags: android, unity3d, лицензирование

Хочу начать изучать Unity 3D, очень хочется писать игры под Андроид. Если что-то напишу, смогу ли это опубликовать в плэй маркете? Или чтобы вытащить АПК из Unity, то надо платить?

Comment: можно. Всё можно. Но если приложение хорошо пойдёт, то понадобится купить лицензию.

Comment: До 100к зеленных в год все бесплатно

Comment: @Xumera_hZ а как же лицензия разработчика за $25 ?)

Comment: @pavel понятно )спасибо большое

Comment: @VadimBugaiov имелось в виду использование бесплатного Unity

Comment: @elik чтобы писать под Android не обязателен Unity. Есть много других движков. И их реально много https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548513/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо большое!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно.Но советую без рекламы и бесплатно-если приложение зайдет, и доходы превысят 100 000$/год, юнити тебя будут сильно пинать или просто прикажут купить платную версию.Иначе удалят приложение из всех магазинов в которых ты выложил это приложение.
UPD: Так же нужно скачать Android SDK для создания апк.Он бесплатный вроде